# Get first available key in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map that stores pointers to an object by their ID.

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, Entity*> entityMap;
entityMap entitymap;
```

To assign an ID to Entity I could just take the newest value in entitymap and increase it by 1.

```
Entity *entity = new Entity;
entity->id = /*newest entity+1*/;
entitymap.insert(std::pair<unsigned int,Entity*>(entity->id,entity));
```

But the number could become unnecessarily big because every now and then an Entity is deleted and removed from the map.

```
std::map<unsigned int,Entity*>::iterator it;
it = entitymap.find(EntityID);
if(it != entitymap.end())
{
    Entity *entity= it->second;
    entitymap.erase(it);
}
delete entity;
```

So I could have a map that holds these values;

```
1,2,4,8,10
```

In which case I'd like the next Entity to claim the ID `3`.

Comment: Just a thought: a 32-bit integer is big enough for about 136 years of seconds. Are you sure it isn't big enough for you IDs? :)

Comment: Doesn't a big integer take up more space than a small one?

Comment: No, a 32 bit integer takes, well, 32 bits of memory (4 bytes on most computers), doesn't matter if its value is 0, 1000, or 100 milions.

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but why have a map where the keys are ints? Wouldn't an array do better? Taking into account that std::map is implemented through binary trees, the lookup times would also be much better (log n vs 1)

Comment: @jrok Then it would be enough in theory, but it's still cleaner to do it the right way, as long as performance doesn't suffer significantly.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu Never really figured out how to make an array with an undefined size. It's probably really easy but I came across a tutorial on maps which worked just as well so I figured I wouldn't bother.. I'll look in to it though, thanks.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: It's quite wise to use a "sparse array" in scenarios like this. Otherwise that's a heck of a lot of memory you're using for no good reason, and you also lose the ability to see at a glance whether a slot is "in use" (unless you also want to null-initialise at least four billion array elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the IDs are ordered numerically, you could walk through the entire map until you find a "hole":

```
unsigned int i = 1; // or whatever your smallest admissable key value is

for (auto it = m.cbegin(), end = m.cend();
                           it != end && i == it->first; ++it, ++i)
{ }

// now i is the next free index
```

This may take long if the map is large and the first hole is near the end. You could check first if the largest key value (given by `m.crbegin()->first`) is significantly larger than `m.size()` before embarking on this exploration.

Comment: The thought occurred to me but it doesn't seem very efficient at all. Would it perhaps be more efficient to add the ID of a removed entity to a vector and make new entities take their ID's from that vector, or if it's empty, the highest value from the map +1 ?

Comment: @natli: That's called a "free list". Yes, that's an option. You should read up in a data structure book on those; you can get some very sophisticated implementations of a free list that are very efficient. You wouldn't have your `std::map` anymore, but if space and performance are critical, it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Kerrek SB The map is an abstract data structure. Iterating over it doesn't necessarily yield the keys in sorted order (or any order at all). As far as I know the STL map is implemented through some sort of binary tree, so your assumption that the IDs are ordered numerically is correct, but if you might want to switch to a hashmap (or any other map implementation) in the future, the assumption would no longer be correct.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu In C++11, [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is ordered by the `Compare` template argument, which defaults to `std::less()`. In C++11, [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) isn't ordered, but `std::map` is.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) of all the freed keys. Every time you free an key you add it to the heap, and every time you use an key you remove it from the heap. Both these operation are O(log n). You would create a heap so that the root node has the smallest key.

If the heap is empty, then you just allocate a new key by incrementing the previous largest key as you would normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list doesn't grow very much, you could at least keep the smallest identifier that's released. Then when you re-use it, search for the next available identifier as mentioned by Kerrek SB.

```
class {
...
    static int g_smallest_free_id; // init to 1
...
};

void delete_id()
{
    if(m_id < g_smallest_free_id) {
        m_id = g_smallest_free_id;
    }
}

void new_id()
{
    int id = g_smallest_free_id;
    // the -1 is because it looks like you start your ids at 1
    // since we skip all the known identifiers before id,
    // the loop is reduced from the current id to the next only
    for(interator it = list.begin() + id - 1;
                  it != list.end(); ++it) {
         // find next available id
    }
}
```

This is pseudo code, shows you that the smallest free identifier has to be a static variable in your class (common to all instances.)

As mentioned in a comment, you could use a vector instead. Although it would not be sorted, you would still not grow identifiers indefinitely. Only drawback of the vector is that you use a little memory... (a lot if you deal with many objects, but so would the map.)

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially slow, depending on how dense your map is, but fairly easy to understand:

```
typedef std::map<Key, Value> Table;

std::optional<Key> findFirstFreeSlot(const Key& start, const Key& end, const Table& table)
{
  for (Key i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (table.find(i) == table.end()) {
        return i;
    }
  }
  return std::none;
}
```